# Merging arrays from all ranks using MPI

Tags: mpi

I have an array of *same length* on all ranks (Lets assume 10). Some values in the array contain the rank of the processor. For example ...

```
Proc 1: [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]

Proc 2: [0 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 0]

Proc 3: [0 0 0 3 3 0 3 0 0 0]
```

Now what is the most efficient way (using MPI-2) that all processors end with the following array

```
[1 2 2 3 3 1 3 2 2 1]
```

which can be thought of as the sum of all arrays (distributed on all ranks). Performance is important as I want to do this fast on 1K+ cores.

Answer (score 11):

This is doable by `MPI_Allreduce()` with `MPI_SUM` or `MPI_MAX` operator. See the documentation of [MPI_Allreduce](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node82.html). It is supposed to be implemented in one of the best possible ways for the given architecture.

```
int arr_a[LEN], arr_b[LEN];
...
// Fill in arr_a
MPI_Allreduce(arr_a, arr_b, LEN, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
// Result is now in arr_b
```

Or if short on memory you could use an in-place operation but that will hurt the performance:

```
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, arr_a, LEN, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used sum as an example as I couldn't think of anything better. I guess its the best option.